# alternative solution for deprecated each function in PHP

Tags: php, each, deprecated

I have some legacy code that uses each to return menu item values

```
function fetch () {

    $item = each( $this->menu );
    if ( $item ) {
        return ( $item['value'] );
    } else {
        reset ( $this->menu );
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to solve this by adding a function that emulates the each function:

```
function each_replacement($arr) {
    $key = key($arr);
    $result = ($key === null) ? false : [$key, current($arr), 'key' => $key, 'value' => current($arr)];
    next($arr);
    return $result;
}
```

And changing the original function fetch to this (found this in another thread:

```
function fetch () {

    $item = this->each_replacement( $this->menu );
    if ( $item ) {
        return ( $item['value'] );
    } else {
        reset ( $this->menu );
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the output is not correct, it only shows the first menu item repeatedly and gets stuck in endless loop, so that doesn't work.

My preference is just to rewrite the code and tried some things like

```
foreach ($this->menu as $item) {  }
```

instead of

```
$item = each( $this->menu )
```

But that gave me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type MenuItem as array
```

If anyone can help me come up with a solution that would be great.

The complete menu code is here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45a3c9c5c24232096744ecd9b915b13982ec551a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About the code:**

1. each() - Return the current key and value pair from an array and
   advance the array cursor
2. current() - Return the current element in an array
3. next() - Advance the internal pointer of an array

Which means each() = current() val following by a next() call

~

Note: I would use a foreach, this is just an explanation how to keep the fetch() function.

**Code:**

```
    /**
     * Iterates over the menu array
     * @return mixed item from menu
     * @access public
     */
    function fetch () {

        $item = current($this->menu);
        if ( $item ) {
            next($this->menu);
            return $item;
        }
        reset($this->menu);
        return false;

    }
```

Test [here](https://repl.it/@xooxx/DearSlategraySeahorse)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I read your explanation and tried both solutions, but unfortunately the menu items don't show, no errors either.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? 

Look here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab4853f8ee0ffa2fd69b7b34baf9828a614dbc25

Comment: I put the complete menu code here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45a3c9c5c24232096744ecd9b915b13982ec551a

Comment: The readMenu is appending values to $this->items array.

$this->menu array is never updated.

Comment: I see $this->menu in the Menu class, but still don't know how to get things working correctly...everything is working correctly with the (deprecated) each function by the way, but I need to get it working without the each function

Comment: return $item; instead of $item->value.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!